Reducing downtime of Statefulset K8S
I am currently in the process of migrating applications from DO droplets (VPS) to Kubernetes (K8S). The old system applications are mostly stateful, so I am facing challenges in minimizing downtime.
For instance, when I move a service to a StatefulSet in K8S, the downtime is relatively high, often exceeding 1 minute. This downtime includes the time taken to terminate the old pods (to handle remaining traffic) and the time to wait for the new pod to become ready (including the time to attach the volume).
I am wondering if there is an existing solution where new pods are created but don't serve traffic until the old pods have successfully terminated their tasks. This would reduce the downtime to just the time taken to terminate the old pods.
I have 3 approach ideas:
One approach is to relocate the app to a Deployment and employ a separate app to distribute the unique KEY. After that, we can use Redis "redlock" to stop new pods from handling traffic until the old pod has shut down and released the lock.
The second option is to maintain the app in two StatefulSets. Another app can be used to manage the update process using a "Blue Green" strategy. When a new StatefulSet is created, it remains locked, similar to the first approach, until the old StatefulSet is terminated by the app orchestration.
Using consistent hashing: may be challenging as it requires numerous changes from the current disorganized system.
Has anyone implemented a system like this or have any ideas about how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!
